# Create RegEx to find such strings?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am new to RegEx in python. I have created a RegEx formula which should find some special string from text but it is not working as exprected;

```
def find_short_url(str_field):
    search_string = r"moourl.com|ow.ly|goo.gl|polr.me|su.pr|bit.ly|is.gd|tinyurl.com|buff.ly|bit.do|adf.ly"
    search_string = re.search(search_string, str(str_field))
    result = search_string.group(0) if search_string else None
    return result
```

It should find all the URL shortner from a text. But the `su.pr` is detecting as surpr from the text. Is there any way to fix it?

```
find_short_url("It is a surprise that it is ...")
```

output

```
'surpr'
```

It can affect other shortner too. Still scratching my head.

Comment: Escape the dot to make it match a literal dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the dots:

```
search_string = r"moourl\.com|ow\.ly|goo\.gl|polr\.me|su\.pr|bit\.ly|is\.gd|tinyurl\.com|buff\.ly|bit\.do|adf\.ly"
```

In regex, a dot matches any character. Escaping them makes them match a literal dot.

Comment: But now it can not find the words. `find_short_url("It is a surprise that it is ... http://goo.gl")` .Return nothing.

Comment: No, Bohemian, `r'a\\.b'` matches ``a\bc`` as `r'...'` is a raw string literal where backslashes are treated as literals.

Comment: Ok. Without raw string except r it works fine.

Comment: @Wiktor so `r"a\.b"` then. see edit.

Comment: I have found also `abc[.]com` escape the dot character, which makes it a character class i guess.

Comment: @DataPsycho agreed. the good thing about `[.]` is you don't have to know how to delimit characters in the context of the combination of the app language and the flavor of regex it uses; which also means the regex is portable.